# Spring and Gradle - adding to the project WebJars Bootstrap

Tags: css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I want to using in my service webjars bootstrap.
I added dependency

```
compile group: 'org.webjars', name: 'bootstrap', version: '4.0.0-alpha.6-1'
```

I register source

```
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/webjars/");
```

I using bootstrap css in thymeleaf

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6-1/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
```

And bootstrap does not work at all. No items. How this service did not see the bootstrap css file? In the project I use, for example, Spring Security. Could it have any effect? And is it worth the trouble of fixing it? What is the speed between a webjars file and such a plain css file in the 'resource' folder?

Answer (score 0):

To add Bootstrap as webjar pls add the following to build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.webjars:bootstrap:4.1.3'
}
```

And attach it to html template:

```
<body>
<script src="/webjars/bootstrap/4.1.3/js"></script>
...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the classPath in your registry

```java
registry
  .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
  .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
```

If you want to access the webjars without defining the version, you'll need to add

```java
implementation 'org.webjars:webjars-locator'
```

If you are using the Spring Framework Version +4.2 you'll need to use `webjars-locator-core`

Then you'll need to add `resourceChain(true)` to the registry entry

Answer (score -1):

You can add `bootstrap.min.css` file like below:

```
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
          rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

A **github example** is given in this link: https://github.com/springframeworkguru/springbootwebapp

**Full tutorial is here:** https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-web-application-part-2-using-thymeleaf/

Comment: Question is about Gradle, not Maven (in provided links).